# What is the relation between perspective, translateZ, scale and height in CSS parallax?

Tags: css, height, transform, parallax, perspective

I've been trying to find out what exactly the relation is between the perspective, transform (more specifically translateZ and scale) and height properties (using vh) are when it comes to pure-CSS parallax.

When using the following numbers, the effect works as expected:
2px perspective, -1px translateZ, 1.7 scale for the parallax-part and 70vh height for the non-parallax-part.
See here: [Working](https://jsfiddle.net/L85wbdt1/)

```
.middle {height: 70vh;}
```

When changing the height of the non-parallax-part to 50vh (while keeping everything else the same), however, the two background images show an overlap before the non-parallax-part comes into view/covers the overlap.
See here: [Overlap showing](https://jsfiddle.net/hw540x6j/)

```
.middle {height: 50vh;}
```

I'm assuming I need to adjust the numbers for perspective, translateZ and scale when I change the vh height, but is there any formula/any rhyme and reason as to how? Or is it trial and error to find a combination that works/doesn't show the overlap?

Answer (score 0):

I have sort of figured it out. If you keep 2px perspective and -1px translateZ, the scale and height relate as follows:

- scale 1.**5** (or higher) needs at least **50**vh height
- scale 1.**6** (or higher) needs at least **60**vh height
- scale 1.**7** (or higher) needs at least **70vh** height
  etc.

However, this only applies for scale 1.5 and up, not down.
Not sure how the scale factor below 1.5 relates to height (yet).